# Overriding just part of a -moz-appearance in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

It is common when writing CSS (especially overlays) for Firefox to use:

`identifier { -moz-appearance: none !important; }`

This removes the default CSS property assignments for the element specified by `identifier`.

But what if you just want to remove *some* of the default property assignments made by a default `-moz-appearance`?

For example, if you want to just change the `line-height` of an element that has a default `-moz-appearance`, you can't just specify `line-height: 20px !important;`.  This won't override the `line-height` specified in the `-moz-appearance`.

The only way I've found to override any part of the `-moz-appearance` is to assign `none` to the appearance, but the problem with doing this is that you lose all the CSS defined by the `-moz-appearance`.

Is there a way to just override a single CSS property of an element that has a `-moz-appearance`?

I suspect the answer is "no", but perhaps I can learn something here.

Comment: Basically,.... NO!